# How to remove error 'unrecognized selector' while trying to login user to QBChat

Tags: ios, quickblox

I'm new to Quickblox for iOS and trying to login user to QBChat but I'm receiving unrecognized selector.

Here is the code:

```css
if ([result isKindOfClass:[QBAAuthSessionCreationResult class]]) {
  QBUUser *currentUser=[QBUUser user];
  currentUser.login=@"test0123";
   currentUser.password=@"test0123";

if (result.success) {
    // Session is created...
    //Login to QuickBlox Chat
    [[QBChat instance] setDelegate: self];
    [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser: currentUser];
  }
}
```

I am receiving following log:

> -[QBChat loginWithUser:] -> Connecting to Chat, hostName: chat.quickblox.com
>   -[QBChat loginWithUser:] -> Chat server endpoint: chat.quickblox.com, User JID:xxxxxxxx
>   -[QBDDXMLElement attributeFloatValueForName:withDefaultValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17442b0e0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ([result isKindOfClass:[QBAAuthSessionCreationResult class]]) {

    if (result.success) {
        QBAAuthSessionCreationResult *res = (QBAAuthSessionCreationResult *)result;
        QBUUser *currentUser = [QBUUser user];

        currentUser.ID = res.session.userID;
        currentUser.login = self.sessionLogin;
        currentUser.password = self.sessionPassword;

        if ([[QBChat instance] isLoggedIn] == NO) {
            [[QBChat instance] setDelegate:self];
            [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:currentUser];
        }

    } else {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for improving my question. But I'm still receiving the same logged error. I have followed a previous answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140132/creating-chat-room-in-quickblox)  in hopes to solve this issue but the issue persists.

Comment: Generally, you should follow the steps on quickblox website instead, which is more up to date: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios

Comment: Experiencing similar unrecognized selector  error with this method:
                `[QBRequest createSessionWithExtendedParameters:parameters successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session) {}`

Comment: You should run, test, and debug the SimpleSample-chat application provided by Quickblox. It might give you some insight into what you're missing. That's the only help/advice I can give you, considering the available information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an old SDK, please try new SDK with CocoaPods http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework#CocoaPods

And also please try sample projects
https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk

they have the same logic that you have and everything works without crashes

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I've gone the cocoapods and ios sample project route and stumbled on the main issue: in QBDDXMLNode.h which states: "Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'libxml/tree.h' file not found." Any ideas? And yes...I have added the frameworks and the necessary flags to the Other Linker Flags.

Comment: use Google :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857531/import-libxml-tree-h-file-not-found-after-xcode-6-1-update
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622684/import-libxml-tree-h-file-not-found-after-xcode-update

Comment: @PhilT also please ensure you set -ObjC in linker flags.